# In a Flask app, how to print each item of a list in the new paragraphs inside my HTML page

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm building a Flask app which is supposed to return all the items in a list as a new line in the HTML page.
For example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to print each item in `list` as a new paragraph in my HTML page, like here:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: That's great, but what is your question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should better follow the [flaskr tutorial on flask web site](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/). It can give you the idea how to pass local variables to the template.

```
@app.route('/')
def your_view():
    your_list= [1,2,3,4]
    return render_template('your_view.html', your_list=your_list)
```

then in your jinja template, iterate over this list.

```
  {% for your_list_element in your_list %}
      <p>{{ your_list_element }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks ....I'm new to Flask.